# How to get a JSON property name matching the naming strategy for a model?

Tags: c#, json.net

Say an application has serializer settings with `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` and I have a model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Name = "content_text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to find a way to get the resulting name a serializer would generate on serialize for each property, so that following would be true:

```
string JsonName<T>(string cSharpPropertyName)
{
    //
}

JsonName<Model>(nameof(Model.Id)) == "id";
JsonName<Model>(nameof(Model.Text)) == "content_text";
```

I'm writing a custom deserializer (JSON converter) for a custom type and I'd like to match my `Model` properties with JSON input without being case insensitive but with the current serializer strategy.

I had idea to just deserialize each incoming JToken wrapped in a new JSON object to a c# `object` and check resulting property name but it doesn't seem to be very efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contract resolver itself to do this job.

Make your `JsonName` method accept an `IContractResolver` as a parameter along with the property name.  The implementation might look something like this:

```
public static string JsonName<T>(string cSharpPropertyName, IContractResolver resolver) where T : class
{
    var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(typeof(T)) as JsonObjectContract;
    var property = contract?.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UnderlyingName == cSharpPropertyName);
    return property?.PropertyName;
}
```

Inside your `JsonConverter`, you can get the contract resolver from the serializer, which is provided as a parameter to `ReadJson`:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var resolver = serializer.ContractResolver;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!